# Is this the correct approach to finding this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

For the following integral with $C=|z|=1$

> $\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz$

I took the approach of recognizing there is a pole of order $n=4$ at $z=0$ to use the Residue
Theorem for pole of order n as below:

> $\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}f(z)dz = 2\pi i~Res(f(z),z_{0})=2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to~z_{0}}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left((z-z_{0})^n\frac{1}{z^{n}}\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz = 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{(4-1)!}\lim_{z\to~z_{0}}\frac{d^{4-1}}{dz^{4-1}}\left((z-0)^{4}\frac{1}{z^{4}}\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz = 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{6}\lim_{z\to~0}\frac{d^{3}}{dz^{3}}\left((z-0)^{4}\frac{1}{z^{4}}\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz = 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{6}\lim_{z\to~0}\frac{d^{3}}{dz^{3}}\left(1\right)\right]$

$\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz = 2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{6}\lim_{z\to~0}~0\right]$

$\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz = 2\pi i\cdot 0$

$\displaystyle \oint_{_{C}}\frac{1}{z^{4}}dz = 0$

Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Not at all, you have found the correct answer. In fact $\int_{C}z^{-n} = 0$ provided that $n\geq 2$. But there is an easier way to do that, noting that $\frac{1}{z^n} = -\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{(n-1)z^{n-1}}$ and $C$ is a smooth curve, the integral is $0$.

Comment: Basic fact: integral of any derivative over a  closed contour is $0$.

Comment: One can also parametrize this integral directly with $z=e^{i\theta}$ and it works out easily. One can also identify the residue as the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series, since $\frac1{z^4}$ is already a (very small) Laurent series! But nothing wrong with the approach in the OP.

Comment: @geetha290krm Unless it is the derivative of, say, $\log\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. We say $f$ is the derivative of $g$ on the contour  if $g'(z)$ exists and equals $f(z)$ at every point of the contour. No branch of log satisfies $(\log z )'=\frac 1 z$ on $|z|=1$.

Comment: @KurtG. The basic fact I stated is a  universal truth and the proof is trivail.

Comment: @geetha290krm No offence intended. If OP reads your comment about $\log$ I have achieved what I wanted: Beware of multivalued functions.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have a constant in numerator and $(z-a)^{n+1}$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ in the denominator, some $a \in \Bbb{R}$, if $n\geq 1$, then the result is zero. Only if $n=0$ is it the case the integral may be non-zero.